Problemas al mostrar imágenes en rutas dinámicas con Github Pages
Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de mostrar imágenes en rutas dinámicas en un proyecto de NextJs que he subido a Github Pages. En local funciona perfectamente, solo tuve que añadir la "/" antes de la ruta y las imágenes me cargan bien. El problema es a la hora de subir el proyecto a Github y ver los cambios en la página vinculada, donde las imágenes no se cargan porque no son encontradas.
He probado con <picture> y <img> y con <Image> de NextJs y a cargar el proyecto con y sin "/" en la ruta y el resultado no cambia.
Añadir que las imágenes se encuentran en una carpeta dentro de public.

tendrías que sacarle la barra al principio de la ruta y ya con eso se tendría que arreglar es decir por ejemplo <img src="img/img.png" /> para ayudarte mejor sube una captura de la orden de tus archivos de tu proyecto.

Ya lo probé sin la "/" inicial y tampoco me carga (la única diferencia es que en local tampoco me carga si lo quito).
He subido de forma provisional el proyecto a este enlace para poder compartirlo y daros más información:
https://github.com/sara-ndonga/Namaste
El archivo en cuestión se encuentra dentro de la ruta src > app > catalogo > [tea]

Tenés la carpeta de imágenes en la carpeta pública, mueve las a la carpeta utils, y llama de ahí las imágenes usando esa ruta de útiles, cuentame si se pudo solucionar o no!

Se solucionó! Muchas gracias Roy

El error finalmente se solucionó moviendo las imágenes que se necesitaban cargar en las páginas dinámicas desde la carpeta public a la carpeta src/app e importándolas con un require.
